# IOT: Is there any way to check serial port are having signal before connecting?

Tags: android, linux, serial-port, uart

I have a range of product types. Some of them only use 2 in 4 serial ports (tty0, tty1, tty2 & tty3). In case my product type only uses tty0 and tty1, I want my app to self-identify these 2 ports and only open FileInputStream to listen to data.
If you have worked with this before. I hope you can help. Thanks!

I tried to use some of command in linux but it only list the available ports, not connected ports.

**Solution:** my problem actually is connecting all above ports may affect another process like Bluetooth. I changed my approach to detect which port is being used by com.android.bluetooth process. Command is `lsof | grep dev/ttyS*` and find is there any bluetooth process.

Sorry for my first time working with IoT system, so the concept may be incorrect at some point.

Comment: "*I want my app to self-identify these 2 ports*" - A serial port is a legacy device that is not "self identifying" nor is the *remote* device that could be connected to it. Do not conflate the local port with a connected remote device. There are crude modem signals, such as DCD, or HW handshake that could be misused to detect a connected (but not necessarily responsive) remote device. You would need a higher-level message protocol to retrieve identification information from a remote device.

Comment: I'm using UART protocol via serial port, is there any way to receive the signal? Thanks!

Comment: @Chuong Tran , The UART protocol you wrote is probably a misunderstanding. The specifications and usage information for the UART interface IC chip cannot be expressed by the name protocol. On the other hand, Perhaps, article like this may be of some help. [Tutorial on how to write basic udev rules in Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks everyone, actually I'm an application developer, not embedded developer. So this is my first time deep dive into this to debug. But I found the solution for my problem, updated in my question's description. Thanks!

Comment: `ttyX`, where `X` is a number are **not** serial devices. They are _consoles_, or pure TeleTYpe devices. You probably meant `ttySx`. Nevertheless, serial interfaces are not discoverable. You need to know in advance what's connected to them. This is usually comes from ACPI or Device Tree platform (HW) descriptions. In some rare (legacy) cases it can be hardcoded in the kernel and/or other applications.